# Passing initial parameters to an ExtJS 4 application

Tags: extjs4

I am absolutely brand new to ExtJS and javascript frameworks, and this is a dead simple question but I just can't seem to find an example.

I am trying to find out how I should simply pass initial arguments from the hosting html page to an ExtJS 4 application - what is the ExtJS 4 equivalent of this very humble line in the app's hosting html page:

```
var myapp = new MyApp({param1:'value1', param2:'value2'});
```

Everything I see re: examples online doesn't pass arguments initially to the application when it starts up.  Is that just not the right idea or something..?

Answer (score 0):

I usually create global variables on the page and then just use them in js.
Something like:

```
//mypage.html

 <script type="text/javascript">
        var loadScansUrl = "<%=Url.Action<ReportScannerRunController>(controller => controller.LoadScans())%>";
        var loadInstancesUrl = "<%=Url.Action<ReportScannerRunController>(controller => controller.LoadInstances(-1))%>";
 </script>
```

Then I use them directly where I need.

```
//myfile.js

Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: loadInstancesUrl, // here is the usage!!!
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            params: this.scanId,
            scope: this,
            success: function (response) {
                var result = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                var comboData = [];
                Ext.each(result.Instances, function (instance) {
                    comboData.push({ Value: instance });
                });
                instances.store.loadData(comboData);
            }
        });
```

Perhaps it's a good idea to collect all this variables into one global object, like:

```
var globalVariables = {};
globalVariables.someVariable = 2;
```

So you'll have one entry point to your global data.

It's just the way I do this, nice to hear how other do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a  singleton Configuration  file in app/Configuration.js , where u define all the variables , urls for global access :

```
Ext.define('myApp.Configuration', {
        singleton : true,
        urls : { actionURL : /d.php, bgotUrl :abcd.php }
});
```

you now need to require this file in Application.js file as 
requires : [ 'myApp.Configuration'] to load it in advance for usage in other files like:

myApp.Configuration.urls.actionURL

So, i guess very clean solution for your application wide settings.
Cheers!